# VBA to return range based on a selection

Tags: vba, excel

I have what I think is a fairly simple VBA task I want to execute. It should, based on a column of cells I select, output the contents of those cells plus cells in next three columns to another place on my spreadsheet.

The code is:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = Selection.Columns("a:d")
```

So, I would select say G2:G10, then it will return what is in G2:J10 in a range beginning with the cell 10 columns over from G2. It should accomplish the same thing as the following code, but without copy-paste.

```
Selection.Columns("a:d").Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).PasteSpecial
```

Thanks for any help!
Jordan

Comment: `Selection.Columns("A:D").Offset(0,10).Value = Selection.Columns("A:D").Value` ?

Answer (score 0):

This will get only the rows that you selected instead of the whole column.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(, 10).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count, 4).Value = Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count, 4).Value
```